# Some questions about "DONT_DELETE_DATA" , how it works, and how do apps use it

Tags: android, uninstallation, android-applicationinfo, package-info

### Background

I'm developing an [**app-manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) app, and I've noticed that there is a way to get a list of "uninstalled apps" (using "[**GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES)" flag) , which are apps that requested to avoid removal of their data upon uninstallation .

Here's what the documentation says:

> Flag parameter to retrieve some information about all applications
>   (even uninstalled ones) which have data directories. This state could
>   have resulted if applications have been deleted with flag
>   DONT_DELETE_DATA with a possibility of being replaced or reinstalled
>   in future.
>
> Note: this flag may cause less information about currently installed
>   applications to be returned.

### The problem

I've tried to investigate more about this feature, but I didn't find almost anything about it, other than this documentation.

### The questions

1. How do such apps request this feature? I can't even find the "DONT_DELETE_DATA" anywhere on the documentation except for what I've written about. Looking on [**this website**](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/0.9_beta/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#DONT_DELETE_DATA), it seems it's a part of the PackageManager class, but I can't see it being public on Eclipse.
2. How long will the data stay?
3. How can I detect such apps? Is there anything to look at [**PackageInfo**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) or [**ApplicationInfo**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) that shows it?
   Is it "[**FLAG_INSTALLED**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#FLAG_INSTALLED)" on the ApplicationInfo, perhaps?
   I've run it, and none of the list of apps that I got have this flag turned off, even though I've installed and uninstalled many apps.
4. Would choosing to uninstall such "ghost"-like apps really remove them?
5. Will I still be able to see those apps on the built in app-manager?
6. Will I still be able to manage such apps?
7. What information can be retrieved of such apps (icon, name, etc,... )? 
   I ask this since the documentation say "this flag may cause less information" .
8. The documentation say that when I use GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES I might get less information about "currently installed applications". Is it a mistake? shouldn't it be "currently **un**-installed applications" ?
9. When an app uses this flag of not removing its data, does it mean only internal-storage, private data, or also external-storage, public data ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java, PackageManager has a deletePackage method which takes flag parameters.

DONT_DELETE_DATA is one of those flags.
So, this is not an attribute of an application, it's a flag to the deletePackage method to tell it to preserve the data while removing an application.

You don't see deletePackage in the javaDocs because the method has a @hide tag.

Comment: So when does it occur? And when does this data get removed? it's really mysterious to me. Can you please try to answer the other questions?

Comment: It occurs when an application invokes the deletePackage() method of the PackageManager. Presumably, this would be an "Application Manager"  type of app. Also, presumably, the data would never get removed. As far as the rest of your questions - sorry, I just don't know.